# revert back from chrome's new tab with google search

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has recently updated its version and when we click on the new tab, It contains google search bar which takes time to load.

Is there any way to revert it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable this feature, go to:

> chrome://flags/

And hit **Ctrl+F**. Search for "**Enable Instant Extended API**". Click disabled in the dropdown below it, then click relaunch now. This should disable the new tab page. Change the flag to enabled if you'd like to re-enable it at any time.

or alternatively, Here's the flag:

> chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api